# htaccess rewrite QueryString disappears in Apache 2.2 but works in 2.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Following is the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([\w-]+)/?$ api.php?method=$1 [QSA]
```

On local Apache 2.4 server, it allows me to rewrite like:

```
/api/create-account/?name=abcd
```

to

```
/api.php?method=create-account&name=abcd
```

On production server, which is Apache 2.2, the request goes to `api.php`. But I find not query string parameter in my script. If I dump `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` or `$_POST`, I only get empty array.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off Multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Multiviews is a mod_negotiation option that tells it to try to match a request to physical files. When it sees a request like `/api/somtehin` and then sees that there's a file named `api.php`, it will map to that file right away, completely bypassing mod_rewrite.

Comment: Do I have to add it in .htaccess?

Comment: @Salman You can add it to the htaccess file or in your vhost config

Comment: Checking the `$_SERVER` dump, it appears that Multiviews in actually enabled by default. I see `[PHP_SELF] => /api.php/create-account/`. But that is not really what I want because I have written the script differently.

Comment: @Salman You want to turn *off* multiviews, there's a `-` in front of `-Multiviews`.

Comment: Tried that, but $_SERVER output is still the same.

Comment: Any chance you have AllowOverride None for that directory on your 2.2 system?

Comment: It was `None` at the beginning, I had that set to `All` as well.