# Can't keep query string on URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I run an Apache server with ISPConfig 3 installed and WordPress. I applied rewrite rules so that all HTTP goes to HTTPS and all WWW goes to non-WWW.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L] 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [QSA,L]
```

I put this in my WordPress htaccess, and the `example.com.vhost` file created by ISPConfig 3.

The problem is now, even with the `QSA` in the flags, the query string is removed. I have tried the flags:

`[L,R]`
`[R=301,L]`
`[R=301,L,QSA]`
`[L,QSA]`
`[QSA,L]`

I have checked `apache2.conf`, `000-default` from ISPConfig, `example.com.vhost`, and `.htaccess` files for any rules that do not have `QSA` or `R` and have not found any.

I'm a RewriteRule novice, but I'm trying to wrap my head around this, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** While in my WP dashboard, I noticed that query strings are present in the URLs. So while on the frontend my server drops the query string, on the backend the query string is preserved. So I'm thinking that the WordPress's `.htaccess` must be the issue, right?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'on the frontend' and 'on the backend' in your edit? Does your Wordpress serve the correct pages, or where/how exactly do your query strings show up before they get 'dropped'?

Comment: So if you visit a page in the frontend with a query string on `http://example.com/frontendpage?q=foo`, then what does the network panel of your browser show, one redirect or two? And is the query string present on them?

Comment: Frontend end just means pages made by WordPress, while backend is WordPress admin panel. I'm typing in the query strings directly into the address bar. Before these strings used to work, they weren't dropped by the server. Now the page is served, but the content on the page is not, because it relies on the query string data.

Comment: I don't see any redirects on the network panel. [This is what is looks like](https://gyazo.com/792f2c1ce7b15528c7904706346fc15c)

Comment: @ashraj98, You need to tick the "Preserve log"  box in Chrome to see the redirects themselves. Possibly there is a plugin in your Wordpress that is removing query strings. If you can test some static file on your website directly from the address bar with some dummy query string, it should not drop the query string, unless the .htaccess actually passes everything to the index file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Test for `www` before test with `https`
No need to add `[QSA]` if you do not add `?` and new query string.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, this doesn't work. Chrome says this results in a redirect loop.

Comment: That can be a problem with cache. Did you try with other browser. Because that was a loop with yours, not with mine...

Comment: Nope, cleared my cache, and also tried Firefox and Edge. Didn't work.

Comment: There must be another problem between the various configurations. Because just this one work well. A test without giving https port. I edit the code.

Comment: Ok, that updated code fixed the redirect loop, but my query strings are still being removed.

Comment: Is there any log I can check to see which configuration file is rewriting the URL and removing the query string?

Comment: I do not know. This is a strange problem, because normally the query string does not change if we do not try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

While experimenting never use the `R=301` *permanent* redirect because it will make live very hard for you. With Firefox you need to delete the entire cache just to try again. A useful trick can be using the private navigation mode to test. Then at least you can ditch it and start up another one.

Query strings would be transferred automatically in a [R] redirect. Unless maybe there is some QSD before or you put a `?` inside the RewriteRule.

Can you try it like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule . https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule . https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work either :( I'm getting a feeling that something else is removing the query string, but I cannot figure out what it is. I've gone through every line of every fine that could have possibly had an effect.

Comment: Maybe you are getting hit by MultiViews  
[Dropped query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361616/htaccess-rewrite-querystring-disappears-in-apache-2-2-but-works-in-2-4)